# Pointers - Casting as Struct Pointer + Malloc

Tags: c, pointers, casting, malloc, sizeof

I have some ideas of what this would do, but I'd like a more professional and experienced explaination.

```
typedef struct{
     char str[50];
     unsigned short num;
}s;

s *name = (s *) malloc(sizeof(s));
```

The first part defines a struct. I have no problem with that
This will create a pointer to "s" struct. `malloc()` returns a memory address that will be cast as a pointer to "s". However, `sizeof(s)` I Believe I am having some issues understanding.
`char str[50];` = 50 bytes.
`unsigned short num;` = 2 bytes.

sizeof(s) returns 52 bytes?
`malloc(sizeof(s))` allocates 52 bytes and returns the first address and casts it as a pointer to "s"?

**One More Question!**
How can I perform error handling with malloc in-line?

Thanks to anyone that can help clarify this!

Comment: [Don't cast the return of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/440558).

Comment: Also, `sizeof` may return a different number depending on structure padding.

Comment: check return address of malloc if it is NULL or not  for error handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In C, we need not cast the return value of `malloc`. malloc returns void* and in C, void* implicitly cast to whatever type you specify...
- The value returned by `sizeof(s)` depends on padding and also on the implementation (cos, `sizeof(unsigned short)` will be different on different platforms...).
- In C, if you want to check for the error, you have to compare the return value of `malloc` with `NULL`.

  if (name ==NULL) exit (1); //EXIT_FAILURE

Answer (score 2):

The value of `sizeof(s)` is implementation and [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specific (it is at least 51 - and it could be 51 on hypothetical weird machines where `sizeof(short)==1` and `short`-s are aligned like `char` is; I can't name any such machine). But on my Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64 system (with [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)) it is 52. And `sizeof` is computed at *compile time*.

> How can I perform error handling with malloc in-line?

The usual practice could be

```
s *name = malloc(sizeof(s));
if (!name) { perror("malloc of name"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```