# C program behaving differently on Mac OSX and Linux

Tags: c, linux, macos, unix, ncurses

I have written a program that creates a sidescrolling marquee effect, and it works perfectly on my Mac's terminal. However, when I run it on my raspberry pi (Raspbian Linux), the effect messes up and starts printing on a new line and doesn't scroll the full length of text. Can anyone figure out what the issue is? I have tried for days now.

```
// Compile: gcc marquee.c -o marquee -lncurses
// Usage: ./marquee filename length row col speed
// Reads text from a file and displays 'length' number of chars 
// scrolling sideways at a given 'row, col' position at some indicated 'speed'

#include    <curses.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h> 
#include    <fcntl.h>

#define ROW 10

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    if(ac != 6){
        printf("marquee [fileName] [row] [col] [speed (1-99)]\n");
        perror("Insuffecient argument count\n"); 
        exit(1); 
    }

    char message[256];
    int text_length;
    int i;
    int k;  
    int orgPos = atoi(av[4]);
    int pos;
    int row = atoi(av[3]);  
    int dir = 1; 
    int maxPos = atoi(av[2]);

    int speed = atoi(av[5]);

    int filedesc = open(av[1], O_RDONLY); 

    if(filedesc < 0) {
        perror("Could not open file");
        exit(1); 
    } 

    if(speed < 10) 
        speed = 500000; 
    if(speed >= 10 && speed < 20) 
        speed = 250000; 
    if(speed >= 20 && speed < 30) 
        speed = 120000; 
    if(speed >= 30 && speed < 40) 
        speed = 100000; 
    if(speed >= 40 && speed < 60) 
        speed = 80000; 
    if(speed >= 60 && speed < 70) 
        speed = 60000; 
    if(speed >= 70 && speed < 80) 
        speed = 40000; 
    if(speed >= 80 && speed < 90) 
        speed = 20000; 
    if(speed >= 90 && speed < 95) 
        speed = 10000; 
    if(speed >= 95 && speed <= 99) 
        speed = 5000; 

    int bytesRead = 0; 
    while(bytesRead == read(filedesc, message, 256) > 0){

    }

    // Get text length
    text_length = strlen(message);

    initscr(); // initialize curses
    clear();
    curs_set(0);

    while(1) {
        clear(); // clear last drawn iteration

        pos = orgPos;

        char * scroll;
        scroll = malloc(2*maxPos);

        for(i = 0; i<2*maxPos; i++) 
        {
            scroll[i] = message[i%text_length];
        }

        for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
                mvaddnstr(row, orgPos, &scroll[i%maxPos], maxPos);
                usleep(speed);
                refresh();
        }
    }

    endwin();

    if(close(filedesc) == -1) 
    {
        perror("Error closing file"); 
        exit(1); 
    }
}
```

There are surely many improvements to be made here, but please let the aim of your debugging be figuring out why this will not run correctly on linux. Here is a sample test case:

```
$ ./marquee scroll.txt 25 0 0 50
```

scroll.txt contains the following:

```
Hello, this is a test for the scrolling marquee.
```

Comment: Wrong compilation command: should use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g marquee.c -o marquee -lncurses` then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow is *not* a *fix-my-bugs* service, so your question is off-topic.

Comment: I meant to pose the question more so as "why does it behave differently between the two OS's?," as one works just fine, the other not; not so much "fix my bugs."

Comment: It does not work file (even on your laptop), you still have an undefined behavior.

Comment: I ran your program on Solaris 11.4, (the only change required was to include `<ncurses.h>` rather than `<curses.h>`). It ran just fine for me, with no terminal window corruption as you mention happens on linux.

When it comes to terminal output differences my first step is to check the terminal type. On Solaris my default termtype is `xterm-256color`. On my Mac running 10.13.4 it is `xterm`.

I then tried several different termtypes:


    TERM=ansi
    TERM=xterm
    TERM=xterms
    TERM=at386
    TERM=dtterm


and they all showed the non-corrupted, scrolling output.

Comment: @JAmesMcPherson: it is not a matter of `TERM`. My answer give some clues about that UB

Answer (score 5):

You have an [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) `char message[256];`. You don't explicitly initialize it, so it contains garbage at start. It is difficult (or even impossible, think of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) or of how the environment is passed, perhaps thru the third argument to `main`) to predict what exact garbage is in it.

You are using `read(filedesc, message, 256)`  but [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) does not add any <kbd>NUL</kbd> byte at end of `message` unless that byte was in the file; so using `strlen(message)` is [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB) and you should be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108).

> it works perfectly

**Wrong**. Sometimes UB appears to work *by accident* (and not "perfectly") when you are out of luck. That is why it is *undefined*. This might be the case under MacOSX. But even if your program appears (wrongly, and by bad luck) to work, it stays very buggy.

UB is undefined, so there is no explanation on the behavior differences without diving into gory implementation details. If you really care about these (but you really should not), study the source of your compiler, your kernel code (and what happens after [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), in particular in [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0)), the generated assembler code (with `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O`) to understand what kind of garbage data is inside `message`. You could spend years to understand all the gory details.

You should replace (notice that your `==` is very wrong)

```
     while(bytesRead == read(filedesc, message, 256) > 0){ //BAD
```

with at least (using the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) and an [assignment expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment)) something which clears `message` and keeps the read byte count:

```
    while ((memset(message, 0, sizeof(message)),
           (byteread = read(filedesc, message, sizeof(message)-1) > 0) {
```

Since the last byte of `message` is never `read`, it keeps its 0 value (and `byteread` is always less than 256, the `sizeof(message)` ...).

There are other bugs in your program. Stay scared (and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21227752/841108) for inspiration).

Try to use the debugger. With [cross-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler), it is possible to [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) for [remote debugging](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Debugging.html#Remote-Debugging). Pass `-g -Wall` to your cross-compiler, if it is some [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Perhaps use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on your Raspberry Pi.

Maybe use also some [static program analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) like [clang-analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/). Caveat, they could require additional skills and annotations (e.g. in [ACSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI/ISO_C_Specification_Language) for Frama-C) to be useful and can give lots of [false alarms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_alarm) (remember that the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem), so don't expect too much from static program analyzers and compilers).

BTW, the correct thinking about uninitialized memory is to believe (this is a useful fiction) that it carries some kind of "disease" which propagates to every thing using it. Of course, that is not what happens inside the computer. But thinking this way will help you to avoid UB.

Comment: `or even impossible, think of ASLR` ASLR randomize virtual address space, not the actual page frames. I don't believe it affects the prediction on the content of an uninitialized memory

Comment: ASLR may (and on Linux does) randomize the initial stack segment address range so affects the stack frame of `main`, e.g. by the `env` third argument to `main`